# new relic - instrumenting an app with multiple threaded objects

Tags: java, multithreading, newrelic

I have a reasonably simple Java app that reads from AWS/SQS and parses the data out using several thread groups.

Threads:

- read from SQS
- collect the output from above threads into 'blocks' by time + other keys
- once 'blocks' are at time send these to threads for writing elsewhere
- clean up

I'd like to use **NewRelic** to see what's happening inside these thread groups but if I put the `@Trace(dispatcher=true)` on more than one of the **run()** functions it stops reading any of them. Instead of seeing traces for all of my functions in each thread I'm not seeing much of anything.

Question:

- how would I gather metrics from an app like this? Or is it even possible?

Answer (score 0):

FWIW - **NewRelic** transaction traces won't be reported for **run()** functions if they never exit.

EG:

```
public void run() {
   while(true) {
      // do some tasks
   }
}
```

What you *can* do is put `@Trace` statements on anything that gets called from the **run()** loop. If these functions exit then traces will get reported back to NR.